# how to import-back a deleted project from same eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

It looks basic question but i don't have solution,

Long back, I soft deleted(physically project in workspace directory) from eclipse workspace. 
I am trying to import that project now. It is saying project already in workspace.

So I am doing copy that project from workspace to other location and, deleting that project from workspace. And importing that project to workspace back. This way, It working fine.

But do you have any better idea than this....

Comment: did you delete the project off the disk?

Comment: are you importing a project from a backup?

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted the project from the disk your best bet would be to restore it from the recycle bin. Otherwise you might need a data-recovery tool.

If the project is completely deleted and you're still getting the "already in workspace" message, check your projects folder. You might have a similarly-named project that was deleted from Eclipse but not the workspace folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `import`, then `import existing project` , and select your project folder present on the disk, Now this is important , Uncheck the `copy projects into workspace` checkbox, and then click `refresh` button. Now you will be able to import the project.

Edit:- This will work assuming you deleted project with default settings, which means the checkbox `Delete contents from disk` was not selected , and the files are still present on your HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Go to import, then click on "General->Existing Projects into Workspace" , then select your project root directory present on the disk. Make sure the **project folder path** is correct. Unchecked all the "Options" checkbox.

Answer (score -1):

Simply delete from hard disk where it previously belong and you are done.

Now try to Import it from anther copy (external source).

Comment: I have imported (I had another backup)

Comment: I think person want to ask that he has deleted project & want to re-import from it back up.